# How to recover a very small section of work from github pages after github erases it, after a commit and sync?

Tags: github, github-pages, create-react-app

I added a small section to my portfolio, Skill Set, and after I made a commit sync and published it I can't find it on my laptop and it's not on the repository on github.com but it's still on my site which is hosted by github pages. Is there anything I could do to recover this really small section of my portfolio?
 www.keithcarrillo.com . At the bottom of the one page portfolio is my skill set section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do check your [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to see if you find a commit with a message regarding skill set: you might get it back that way (with [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)).

If that is not working, you can at least create a new commit with the content you can still scrap form your website.

Comment: Thanks VonC I ended up finding a backup. I forgot I had quickly made it, from copying and pasting. But now I that when I publish my work it's not making it to the repository online, it must of done that before. You ever encountered that kind of problem with the Github desktop app, where you publish it but there's no note of it on Github.com.